# How do I return associated items in a model using ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've been struggling with rails models a bit and could use some guidance. I have two models: Package and Package_item.  Packages have many package_items associated to them and I'm trying to figure out how to return the package information along with the array of packge_items in a single method.

```
class Package < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :package_item

  def self.dump
    Package.find(:all,
        :select => "packages.*, packge_items.*")
  end
end

class PackageItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :package
  belongs_to :product
end
```

I created Package.dump and it isn't returning the package_items.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want this:

```
Package.includes( :package_items ).all
```

(**Note:** Passing a second option to `find` is officially deprecated, and passing `:all`, `:first`, etc. to `find` will be deprecated in Rails 3.2 (I think). You should use the finder methods `Package.all`, `Package.first`, etc. instead. Basically the only time you should be using `find` is when you have an ID or IDs to pass as the only parameter(s).

If you want you can create a scope for this, which is often preferable to explicitly defining a class method:

```
class Package < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :package_items

  scope :with_items, includes( :package_items )
end
```

Then you can just call e.g. `Package.with_items`.

Comment: Thanks! This makes perfect sense, but it isn't working for me.  Package.includes( :package_items ).all still only shows the packages and not the items.  There is data in the database as well.  **btw this is my first rails app.

Comment: I'm more confused now because when I launch rails console and run Package.includes( :package_items ) I see it run two queries.  The first being SELECT * FROM `packages`, which returns 3 records and the second being SELECT `package_items`.* FROM `package_items` WHERE `package_items`.`package_id` IN (1,2,3) which doesn't seem to return anything, but that query should be pulling 3 records and I verified the data is correct.

Comment: Odd. When you do, say, `Package.includes( :package_items ).first.package_items` what do you get? Do you have `package_items` records with those `package_id` values?

Comment: When I typed in `Package.includes( :package_items ).first.package_items` it did find the 3 items correctly.  Yes, there are package_items for package_id 1.

Comment: Maybe I'm miss understanding how models work.  I was expecting if I call `Package.includes( :package_items ).all` it would return a multi-dimensional array like this:
{  
  id : '1',   
  name : 'Package 1,   
  items:  
    {
      title : 'Soap' , 
      price : '10.00'
    }  
    {
      title : 'Shampoo',
      price : '12.00'
    }
}

Comment: Almost, but what it returns is an array of `Package` objects, and each object will have a `package_items` method which returns the array of the associated `PackageItem` objects. Does that make sense?

Comment: ahh got it now. Thanks and yes it makes sense!